# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\binom{2n} n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, binomial-coefficients

Calculate
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\binom{2n} n$$
without use Stirling's Formula.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The limit does not exist. There is only an asymptotic formula.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289031/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-fracn22n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\binom{2n} n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n} k \binom{n}{n-k} \geq \binom{n}1 = n$$

Comment: That's a delightfully weak estimate! +1

Answer (score 4):

The limit is $+\infty$.

$$\frac {(2n)!}{n!n!} = \frac{2^n n! (2n-1)!!}{n!n!}  = 2^n\frac{ (2n-1)!!}{n!}= 2^n\frac{ 1\times 3\times \dots \times (2n-1)}{1\times 2\times \dots \times n} .$$
The first factor goes to infinity quite rapidly and the second factor is quite obviously increasing and positive.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to use the ratio test:
$$
\frac{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{(2n+2)!n!n!}{(2n)!(n+1)!(n+1)!}=
\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\to 4,
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Hence
$$
\binom{2n}{n}\to\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have:

$${2n\choose n}-{2n\choose n-1}=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$$

These are simply [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), by the way.
The LHS is an integer, and the RHS is positive, hence, it's a positive integer, and especially it's $\ge1$.

Thus

$${2n\choose n}\geq n+1$$

Answer (score 1):

By repeated use of the identity $\binom{m}{k}=\frac{m-k+1}{k}\binom{m}{k-1}$, we can see that
$\binom{2n}{n} \geq \binom{2n}{k}$ 
for all $k$.

By the binomial theorem, $4^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}$. As this sum has $2n+1$ terms, the largest of which is $\binom{2n}{n}$, we have
$$
\binom{2n}{n} \geq \frac{4^n}{2n+1}
$$
which in particular implies that the sequence $\left\{\binom{2n}{n}\right\}$ diverges to $+\infty$.