# Evaluate $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} $

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, factorial, infinity

I'm completely stuck evaluating $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} $ how would I go about solving this?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006352/calculate-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-binom2n-n

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: for combinatorial reasons (in how many ways can you choose $n$ objects from $n$ pairs of objects?),
$$\binom{2n}n\ge2^n\ ,$$
so
$$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac1{\binom{2n}n}\le\frac1{2^n}\ .$$

Comment: Clever! Combinatorial arguments are always appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

As all terms are positive, we have $$0 \leq \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} =  \frac{n!}{2n \cdot \dots \cdot (n+1)} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+n} \leq \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

So then as

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = 0$$

It follows that

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = 0$$

Edit:

For what it's worth if you want quick justification of the second inequality step:

$$k \leq n \implies 2k \leq k + n \implies \frac{k}{k+n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Recalling the Stirling's approximation $$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}
 $$ we have $$\sqrt{2\pi}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}{\left(2n\right)^{2n+1/2}e^{-2n}}=0.
 $$

Answer (score 2):

Since each term is bounded above by $2^{-n}$, I guess the answer must be zero.

Answer (score 2):

> Use Stirling's Approximation: 
>   $$n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} .n^n e^{-n}$$

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} $$
$$ =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2 \pi n .n^{2n} e^{-2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi 2n} .(2n)^{2n} e^{-2n}} $$
$$ =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}=0$$

Comment: It's the same that I wrote.